# Apache Upload path not writable

Tags: php, apache

I have a Apache/2.4.6 server running on a RedHat server. I am running a slim application at the root of the weber server in `/var/www/html/`.

I want to upload and image and save it to a specified folder. I can run the app perfectly fine  on my local apache environment.

Here is my simple controller function:

```
public function test($request, $response, $args)
{

$files = $request->getUploadedFiles();


if (empty($files['file'])) 
    return $response->withJson(['message' => 'Could not find file'])->withStatus(400); 

$file = $files['file'];
$fileName = $file->getClientFilename();

//app and images folder both ahve 777 permissions
$file->moveTo('/var/www/html/app/images/{$fileName}');

return $response->withStatus(200)->write('Test Method');

}
```

I can echo the file name and see it is there it just move the file I get unwritable path. I don't understand why.

Comment: I assume you're using the Slim framework there? If so, what is the _exact_ error message you're getting? Try to match it here: https://github.com/slimphp/Slim/blob/f6884a7425e4ccf031ff8dda30c14e196bb67156/Slim/Http/UploadedFile.php#L223-L253

Answer (score 0):

This was an issue caused by SEL(Security Enhanced Linux) which comes activated with RedHat. Apparently SEL does not allow uploads to any destination by default regardless of folder permissions and you have to manually allow this. I was able to finally upload using the following command:

```
chcon -R unconfined_u:object_r:httpd_sys_rw_content_t:s0 /var/www/app/images
```

I don't know much about SEL so unfortunately can't add more detail to this other than this solution worked for me.